# How can I wait for an item sent to a queue to complete?

Tags: rust

I have a priority queue that I send values to.  These values are then aggregated onto another value.   However, I want to wait until that value is processed.

Here's some pseudocode to demonstrate the problem:

```
let heap = BinaryQueue::new();


struct HeapConsumer<'a> {
    heap: &'a mut BinaryHeap<Task>,
    aggregate_state: &'a mut i64,
}

struct Task {
   value: i64,
   committed: bool
}

impl<'a> Future for HeapConsumer<'a> {
    type Output = ();

    fn poll(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        if let Some(mut res) = self.heap.pop() {
            *self.aggregate_state += res.value;
            res.committed = true;
            Poll::Pending
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Future for Task {
    type Output = ();

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        match self.commited {
           true => Poll::Completed,
           false => Poll::Pending
        }
    }
}


consumer = HeapConsumer(heap: heap, aggregate_state: 0)

let consumer_thread = async move {
    consumer.await
}

let producer_thread = async move {
   let task1 = Task {value: 2, committed: false} 
   let task2 = Task {value: 1, committed: false}

   heap.push(task1)
   heap.push(task2)
   task1.await
}
```

I know this code violates borrow rules, but it's just an outline of what I'd like to do.  It also could be completely the wrong approach.

However, I'm just trying to find a way to send tasks to a consumer that I can wait upon to complete.

Comment: I feel that the future approach seems like a weird way of going about it.

Comment: Think I've got it, I need to use notify.  Will fill in answer later.

Comment: *These values are then aggregated onto another value. However, I want to wait until that value is processed.* — you want to be notified for _every_ value? How is the queue being processed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution wasn't to use any fancy future stuff, but to use Notify.

```rust
use tokio::sync::Notify;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Task {
    value: i64,
    completed: Arc<Notify>
}

impl Task {
    fn new(v: i64) -> Self {
        Task { value: v, completed: Arc::new(Notify::new()) }
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for Task {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        self.value.partial_cmp(&other.value)
    }
}
impl Ord for Task {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        self.value.cmp(&other.value)
    }
}

impl PartialEq for Task {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.value == other.value
    }
}
impl Eq for Task {}


let heap: Arc<Mutex<BinaryHeap<Task>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(BinaryHeap::new()));

let adding_notification = Arc::new(Notify::new());

let consumer_adding_notification = adding_notification.clone();
let mut consumer_heap = heap.clone();

let consumer = tokio::spawn(async move {
    let mut state: i64 = 0;
    loop {
        consumer_adding_notification.notified().await;
        let mut locked_heap = consumer_heap.lock().await;
        if let Some(result) = locked_heap.pop() {
            state += result.value;
            result.completed.notify_one();
        } else {
            break
        }

        drop(locked_heap);
    }

    println!("Complete - {}", state)
});

let producer_adding_notification = adding_notification.clone();
let mut producer_heap = heap.clone();

let handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
    let mut locked_heap = producer_heap.lock().await;
    let t1 = Task::new(1);
    locked_heap.push(t1.clone());
    drop(locked_heap);
    adding_notification.clone().notify_one();
    adding_notification.clone().notify_one();
    let res = t1.completed.notified().await;
    println!("task completed");
});

future::join(handle, consumer).await;
```

This allows me to wait for tasks to be consumed.